# Convergence of the series $\sum_{n\geq 2}\text{log}(1+\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}})$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence

How can I determine  the convergence and absolute convergence of $$\sum_{n\geq 2}\text{log}\left(1+\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}\right)$$
I have seen that the series $$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}$$ converges (not absolutely).

Comment: We can write $\ln(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+O(x^3)$ and replace $x$ by $\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}$.

Answer (score 0):

As  Jean-Claude Colette
commented,

$\begin{array}\\
s(m)
&=\sum_{n=2}^m\log\left(1+\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}\right)\\
&=\sum_{n=2}^m\left(\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}+\frac{1}{2n}+O(\frac1{n^{3/2}})\right)\\
&=\sum_{n=2}^m\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}+\sum_{n=2}^m\frac{1}{2n}+\sum_{n=2}^mO(\frac1{n^{3/2}})\\
\end{array}
$

and the first and third sums converge
and the second sum diverges
so the sum diverges
both conditionally
and absolutely.